# Drag and Drop in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, drag-and-drop

I have a number of vector layers, I want to be able to drag a feature off the map and drop it into a native application.  Note, I do not want to move the features around, I already do that when in a particular mode.

I've already got the transfer working from a list I build up in the page when users select features on the map using html5 drag and drop, but it's a bit clunky having to select the feature then drag and drop the list item.

I can not see anything in Openlayers that will allow me to handle the `ondragstart` event for a feature :-(

Comment: Hi I'm also searching a solution for this..Please update if you get any solution for this..Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry, still stuck on this.  If you find a solution I'd appreciate hearing about it